# How to extract data from array in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

My slider is running dynamically with feature image from my posts. I want slider id and I am getting it here with this array. I need to disable the slider image which have expired defined by end date.

```
Array([791]=>1 [792]=>2 [793]=>3 [794]=>4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the name of the array but just do:

```
yourArray[791]
```

and then whatever you wanna do with it.

Comment: how to get array index which is the id, i needed

Comment: @SaralSharma The code I provided will give you the value 1. Not sure what you're asking.